# How to compress multy files to one zip by logback?

Tags: logging, compression, logback

Our project will produce about 100GB logs per day.So we try to use logback to compress these logs to save disk capacity.

But sadly, I can only find way to compress one file each time.

- What I want is: hour1.log, hour2.log, hour3.log => zip up to
  hour1-3.log.zip
- But what I can get with logback is: hour1.log, hour2.log, hour3.log => hour1.log.zip, hour2.log.zip, hour3.log.zip.

The configuration I use is as follows:

```
<rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">   
  <fileNamePattern>${catalina.home}/%i.log.gz</fileNamePattern>   
  <minIndex>1</minIndex>   
  <maxIndex>3</maxIndex>   
</rollingPolicy>   

<triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">   
  <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>   
</triggeringPolicy>
```

If each log file is 50MB(if each file 1GB, it will hard to open and edit), it means I will have 2000 zip files(totally 100GB) under log path, that would be too many and ridiculous.

So please help me.Is there any tricks or tips, to achieve what I want. Cool as logback shouldn't be such less capibility.

Answer (score 0):

After checking logback's source code, I can tell that, it does not support compress multifiles.In other words, logback can achive "one" log file in two ways, rename this log or zip this single one log.And of cause do some rolling on proper time point.

In one word, logback(1.2.3) does not support compress multi files to one zip file.